# R//ggplot2: Dynamic title when combining facet_wrap and for loop

Tags: r, loops, dictionary, ggplot2, facet

I have a spatialtemporal dataset with various indicators for a set of location that I wish to map overtime.

Here is my facet_wrap + loop

```
#basemap
basemap <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data= country_adm2) +
  coord_sf() +
  theme_void() 
print(basemap)

#joining dataframe to polygons
df_poly <- left_join(country_adm2, df, by= "County") ##joins the data by County.

#loop & facet_wrap plots
## This goes over the dataset (df_poly) to plot the the three variables, and facet_wrap over ~Date to see time variation (over 12 months)

for(i in df_poly[40:42]){ ## the vars I wish to plot  to iterate the temporal map through
imap <- basemap + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = i), data= df_poly ) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "cividis", direction= 1, alpha= 1, )+
  facet_wrap(~ Date) + ##the temporal facet_wrap
  ggtitle(paste0("Indicators:", i)) +
  labs(fill = "% of\ncovered population")
  print(imap)
}
```

The problem is that instead of having the actual names of var `i` in `ggtitle` I get the first value. How do I get to iterate through the `names(df_poly[40:42])` properly for each of the plots? I looked at various ways but none of them worked.

I reckon that the way I make the loop seems to be the issue. I assume I need to loop over a list rather than directly the dataframe, however I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: hi. kindly make your question reproducible. This is how:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example     Ideally, make the whole thing on inbuilt data. When trying to reproduce your own problem on other data, you will often get to the solution by yourself and have learned much more from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You have to loop over the names of your vars. I added comments starting with ## where I changed your code.

```
#basemap
basemap <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data= country_adm2) +
  coord_sf() +
  theme_void() 
print(basemap)

#joining dataframe to polygons
df_poly <- left_join(country_adm2, df, by= "County") ##joins the data by County.

#loop & facet_wrap plots
## This goes over the dataset (df_poly) to plot the the three variables, and facet_wrap over ~Date to see time variation (over 12 months)

## loop over the names of the vars to plot
for(i in names(df_poly)[40:42]){ ## the vars I wish to plot  to iterate the temporal map through
  imap <- basemap + 
    ## Convert names to symbols using!!sym()
    geom_sf(aes(fill = !!sym(i)), data = df_poly ) +
    scale_fill_viridis(option = "cividis", direction= 1, alpha= 1, )+
    facet_wrap(~ Date) + ##the temporal facet_wrap
    ggtitle(paste0("Indicators:", i)) +
    labs(fill = "% of\ncovered population")
  print(imap)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a whole lot @stefan. The solution worked exactly as intended. 
For my understanding: 

- `i in names(df_poly)[40:42]) { ` takes the names in the dataframe to make a list instead of the columns themselves, like in my example. Why (df)[x:y] rather than (df[x:y])?
<br>
- `!!sym(i)` then converts the names in i to symbol. I am not sure what it means concretely beside that it allows the identification of the matching variable rather than just its name

- then in the `ggtitle` call, the i pulls the names of the variable rather than its values.

Comment: Hi anatase. 1. names(df) returns a vector with var names. 2. From this vector I extract the values 42:44, which gives me the names of the vars I want to plot as strings or characters. 3. But ggplot2 doesn't like strings. (; It prefers symbols. That's why we have to convert the strings to symbols with the weird !!sym(). However, the details of that are more advanced and is called "tidy evaluation".