# Creating multiple scatter plots with a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I am looking for a way to use a for loop to loop through multiple columns of a csv and plot them.

Here is an example of how I have been making a scatter plot:
ggplot(top_scorers, aes(x=`Win%`,y=`PER`))

Top_scorers is the name of the csv with Win% and PER being columns in the file. I was hoping for a way to keep the x value the same while looping through different columns for the y value. If this is confusing please let me know and I will try to clear up any issues. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R//ggplot2: Dynamic title when combining facet\_wrap and for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883865/r-ggplot2-dynamic-title-when-combining-facet-wrap-and-for-loop)

Comment: Have you considered dplyr pivot_longer to create a long data frame, then using ggplot facet with free axes to create the plots you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `lapply` based solution over the columns of your dataframe. Using you want to keep the first one as `x` dimension, use `aes_string` in `ggplot`

```r
mtcars
library(ggplot2)

lapply(colnames(mtcars)[2:length(colnames(mtcars))], function(nm){
  ggplot(mtcars) +
    geom_point(aes_string(x =colnames(mtcars)[1],
                          nm))
})
```